# C# backgroundwork / progress bar not updating

Tags: c#, winforms

```
string[] idit = File.ReadAllLines(textBox2.Text);
foreach (string barcoutn in idit){
    barcountmax++;

}
foreach (string ids in idit){
    //do sql stuff
    barmovement++;    
    bgw1.ReportProgress(barmovement);
}


private void bgw1_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e){
    progressBar1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage; 
}
```

My progressbar properties are set from the barcountmax for the max value and min value = 0.

I can't seem to get my progress bar to update, what am i missing?

Comment: @Nix: Looks like it has a Progressbar and a BackgroundWorker

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Right now, you only update at the end

```
foreach (string ids in idit)
{
    //do sql stuff
    barmovement++;
}
bgw1.ReportProgress(barmovement);
```

You need to update as you go:

```
foreach (string ids in idit)
{
    //do sql stuff
    barmovement++;
    bgw1.ReportProgress(barmovement);
}
```

---

You need to call [ReportProgress](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ka89zff4.aspx) with an int value from 0 to 100.  If you're calling it with `barmovement` directly, this is potentially a problem.  For details, see the help for [ReportProgress](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ka89zff4.aspx):

> percentProgress
>
> Type: System.Int32
>
> The percentage, from 0 to 100, of the background operation that is complete.

Comment: that was a typo in the posting, code has that inside the foreach loop though +

Comment: but couldn't i somehow report a total here? i mean i have like 1 million entries and i just want to know if i'm on record 103406

Comment: @Mike: Nope - BackgroundWorker always reports progress as a percentage.  You need to compute a percentage, and report that.

Comment: so what am i looking for to accomplish what i need?

Answer (score 2):

Did you set `WorkerReportsProgress` to true? It is false by default.